# Trouble getting simple Kafka producer going

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I'm running Kafka locally on my Mac Pro (Sierra; 10.12.6) just to get started with development. I've started ZooKeeper and a Kafka server (0.11.0.1):

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

I've got topics created:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
__consumer_offsets
access
my-topic
```

(not sure what __consumer_offsets is, I created the other two).

I've installed kafka-python (1.3.4).
My sample program is dead simple:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
producer.send('my-topic', 'Another message')
```

But it croaks with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "produce.py", line 3, in <module>
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 347, in __init__
    **self.config)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 220, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 861, in check_version
    raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

Ideas? Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Did you try out what i suggested , else can you share what solved your problem ...

Comment: Yes - just a change to the config file got it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if kafka broker is really running at 9092. try running the `kafka-console-producer.sh  --broker-list localhost-9092 --topic my-topic` to see if you got the broker instance is really running. You can also see the log when you run kafka-start to see which port and url kafka instance runs on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please insure that you have the setting defined in the server.config file 
 `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092` .

It might be possible that the host name resolution is giving some other host name , by default Kafka uses `java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wurstmeister/kafka, please notice that in Kafka's last version many parameters have been deprecated.
Instead of using -

`KAFKA_HOST:
KAFKA_PORT: 9092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: <IP-ADDRESS>
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092`

you need to use -

`KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://<IP-ADDRESS>:9092`

view [this link](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/wiki/Connectivity) for more details